# Is it possible to speed up my function for creating a correlation matrix?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, correlation

I have written the following function to estimate the pairwise correlations of multinomial variables using so-called [Cramér's V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V). I use the `vcd` package for this purpose, but to my knowledge there is no existing function that would create a symmetrical correlation matrix of V from a matrix or `data.frame` similar to `cor`.

The function is:

```
require(vcd)
get.V<-function(y){
  col.y<-ncol(y)
  V<-matrix(ncol=col.y,nrow=col.y)
  for(i in 1:col.y){
    for(j in 1:col.y){
      V[i,j]<-assocstats(table(y[,i],y[,j]))$cramer
    }
  }
  return(V)
}
```

However, for large numbers of variables it gets relatively slow.

```
no.var<-5
y<-matrix(ncol=no.var,sample(1:5,100*no.var,TRUE))
get.V(y)
```

As you increase `no.var` computing time may explode. Since I need to apply this to a `data.frame` of lengths 100 and higher, my question is, whether it is possible to 'speed up' my function by more elegant programming, maybe. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming the calculation is commutative, you can just do half the calculations.  Beyond that you'll have to optimize `assocstats`, which may well be possible as it seems to do a bit more than just the raw calculation you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are best off using the vectorized version of outer like Tyler suggested. You can still get a performance boost by writing a function to calculate just the Cramer's V. The `assocstats` function uses `summary` on the table and that calculates a lot of statistics you don't want. If you reply the call to `assocstats` to a a user defined function along the lines of

```
cv <- function(x, y) {
    t <- table(x, y)
    chi <- chisq.test(t)$statistic
    cramer <- sqrt(chi / (NROW(x) * (min(dim(t)) - 1)))
    cramer
}
```

This new function, by calculating only Cramer's V, runs in about 40% of the time required for `assocstats`. You could potentially speed it up again my reducing the `chisq.test` to something that only calculates the chi square test statistic.

Even if you just adjust your loop index values to realize you have a symmetric matrix with 1 on the diagonals and use this `cv` function instead of `assocstats` you are looking at easily a 5 fold increase in performance.

Edit: As requested, the full code I've been using to get a 4x speed up is

```
cv <- function(x, y) {
  t <- table(x, y)
  chi <- suppressWarnings(chisq.test(t))$statistic
  cramer <- sqrt(chi / (NROW(x) * (min(dim(t)) - 1)))
  cramer
}

get.V3<-function(y, fill = TRUE){
  col.y<-ncol(y)
  V<-matrix(ncol=col.y,nrow=col.y)
  for(i in 1:(col.y - 1)){
    for(j in (i + 1):col.y){
      V[i,j]<-cv(y[,i],y[,j])
    }
  }
  diag(V) <- 1 
  if (fill) {
    for (i in 1:ncol(V)) {
      V[, i] <- V[i, ]
    }
  }
  V
}
```

It looks to be very similar to what Hadley suggests below, although his version of the function to get Cramer's V uses `correct = FALSE` in `chisq.test`. If all the tables are larger than 2x2, the setting on `correct` doesn't matter. For 2x2 tables, the results will vary depending on the argument. It is probably best to follow his example and set it to `correct = FALSE` so that everything is calculated the same regardless of the table size.

Comment: I think this actually is the wisest approach. +1  Then combine with sgibb's solution and boom.

Comment: I did a little benchmark of the code posted by @tomka, the changed loop index suggested by @sgibb and then the new function for Cramer's V I posted above. With `no.var = 50`, the starting code took an average of 5.212 seconds. Moving to @sgibb's loop index changes cuts that in half to 2.557 seconds. Adding the "hand coded" calculation for Cramer's V cuts it down to 1.249 seconds. The loops cut the time in half and then using the simpler function did it again for a total run time about 24% of the starting code.

Comment: Can you post your code (combination of hand coded version and @sgibb's loop) as `get.V4` , please?

Comment: Tomka, the full code that I've been using is posted above. You will need to change the `3` in `get.V3` to `get.V4` or whatever number you want to set it as.

Answer (score 18):

As well as the reducing the number of tests performed, or otherwise
optimising the running of the whole function, we might be able to make
`assocstats` faster. We'll start by establishing a test case to make
sure we don't accidentally make a faster function that's incorrect.

```
x <- vcd::Arthritis$Improved
y <- vcd::Arthritis$Treatment
correct <- vcd::assocstats(table(x, y))$cramer
correct

## [1] 0.3942

is_ok <- function(x) stopifnot(all.equal(x, correct))
```

We'll start by making a version of `assocstats` that's very close to the
original.

```
cramer1 <- function (x, y) {
  mat <- table(x, y)

  tab <- summary(MASS::loglm(~1 + 2, mat))$tests

  phi <- sqrt(tab[2, 1] / sum(mat))
  cont <- sqrt(phi ^ 2 / (1 + phi ^ 2))

  sqrt(phi ^ 2 / min(dim(mat) - 1))
}
is_ok(cramer1(x, y))
```

The slowest operation here is going to be `loglm`, so before we try
making that faster, it's worth looking for an alternative approach. A
little googling finds [a useful blog
post](http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2011/06/example-839-calculating-cramers-v.html).
Let's also try that:

```
cramer2 <- function(x, y) {
  chi <- chisq.test(x, y, correct=FALSE)$statistic[[1]]

  ulength_x <- length(unique(x))
  ulength_y <- length(unique(y))

  sqrt(chi / (length(x) * (min(ulength_x, ulength_y) - 1)))
}
is_ok(cramer2(x, y))
```

How does the performance stack up:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  cramer1(x, y),
  cramer2(x, y)
)

## Unit: microseconds
##           expr    min     lq median     uq  max neval
##  cramer1(x, y) 1080.0 1149.3 1182.0 1222.1 2598   100
##  cramer2(x, y)  800.7  850.6  881.9  934.6 1866   100
```

`cramer2()` is faster. `chisq.test()` is likely to be the bottleneck, so
lets see if we can make that function faster by doing less:
`chisq.test()` does a lot more than compute the test-statistic, so it's
likely that we can make it faster. A few minutes careful work reduces
the function to:

```
chisq_test <- function (x, y) {
  O <- table(x, y)
  n <- sum(O)

  E <- outer(rowSums(O), colSums(O), "*")/n

  sum((abs(O - E))^2 / E)
}
```

We can then create a new `cramer3()` that uses `chisq.test()`.

```
cramer3 <- function(x, y) {
  chi <- chisq_test(x, y)

  ulength_x <- length(unique(x))
  ulength_y <- length(unique(y))

  sqrt(chi / (length(x) * (min(ulength_x, ulength_y) - 1)))
}
is_ok(cramer3(x, y))
microbenchmark(
  cramer1(x, y),
  cramer2(x, y),
  cramer3(x, y)
)

## Unit: microseconds
##           expr    min     lq median     uq  max neval
##  cramer1(x, y) 1088.6 1138.9 1169.6 1221.5 2534   100
##  cramer2(x, y)  796.1  840.6  865.0  906.6 1893   100
##  cramer3(x, y)  334.6  358.7  373.5  390.4 1409   100
```

And now that we have our own simple version of `chisq.test()` we could
eek out a little more speed by using the results of `table()` to figure
out the number of unique elements in `x` and `y`:

```
cramer4 <- function(x, y) {
  O <- table(x, y)
  n <- length(x)
  E <- outer(rowSums(O), colSums(O), "*")/n

  chi <- sum((abs(O - E))^2 / E)
  sqrt(chi / (length(x) * (min(dim(O)) - 1)))
}
is_ok(cramer4(x, y))
microbenchmark(
  cramer1(x, y),
  cramer2(x, y),
  cramer3(x, y),
  cramer4(x, y)
)

## Unit: microseconds
##           expr    min     lq median     uq  max neval
##  cramer1(x, y) 1097.6 1145.8 1183.3 1233.3 2318   100
##  cramer2(x, y)  800.7  840.5  860.7  895.5 2079   100
##  cramer3(x, y)  334.4  353.1  365.7  384.1 1654   100
##  cramer4(x, y)  248.0  263.3  273.2  283.5 1342   100
```

Not bad - we've made it 4 times faster just using R code. From here, you
could try to get even more speed by:

- Using `tcrossprod()` instead of `outer()`
- Making a faster version of `table()` for this special (2d) case
- Using Rcpp to compute the test-statistic from the tabular data

Comment: I think there is an error somewhere. `cramer4` does not give the same estimates for V as `assocstats`. Could not spot it yet though.

Comment: @tomka Can you provide more details? It works with that one sample input

Comment: I have found why the version 4 fails. It s because of min(dim(O)). In my data, I have dim(O) = [42, 518] and length(unique(data$DateLet))
 519 (42 is Ok however). I can't say why but it's clearly the reason. Should not be that hard to workaround. Don't know if it is linked but I use data.table lib.

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce the calculation time by calculate only one half of your matrix:

```
get.V2 <-function(y){
  cb <- combn(1:ncol(y), 2, function(i)assocstats(table(y[, i[1]], y[, i[2]]))$cramer)
  m <- matrix(0, ncol(y), ncol(y))
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- cb
  diag(m) <- 1
  ## copy the lower.tri to upper.tri, suggested by @iacobus
  for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
    m[i, ] <- m[, i]
  }
  return(m)
}
```

---

EDIT: added @iacobus suggestion to populate the upper.tri of the matrix and added a little benchmark:

```
library("vcd")
library("qdapTools")
library("rbenchmark")

## suggested by @TylerRinker
get.V3 <- function(y)v_outer(y, function(i, j)assocstats(table(i, j))$cramer)

set.seed(1)
no.var<-10
y<-matrix(ncol=no.var,sample(1:5,100*no.var,TRUE))

benchmark(get.V(y), get.V2(y), get.V3(y), replications=10, order="relative")
#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#2 get.V2(y)           10   0.992    1.000     0.988    0.000          0         0
#1  get.V(y)           10   2.239    2.257     2.232    0.004          0         0
#3 get.V3(y)           10   2.495    2.515     2.484    0.004          0         0
```

Comment: I was working on an answer along these same lines and can't figure out how to copy the lower triangle into the upper either. I ended up having to use a loop that set `V[i, ] <- V[, i]`. It wasn't too expensive as it only has to run `nrow(V)` times which is going to be much less than `nrow(V)^2 / 2` times required to populate the matrix.

Comment: @iacobus: Thanks, I added your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks.  My approach saves programming time but certainly does not reduce computational time +1  PS I am testing on 1000 variables and am still waiting for the process to complete.

Comment: `m[upper.tri(m)] <- cb` ?

Comment: @hadley: `m[upper.tri(m)] <- cb` will fill the upper triangle columwise but we want to mirror the lower triangle at the diagonal and have to fill it rowwise. That's why something like `m[upper.tri(m)] <- m[lower.tri(m)]` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

This uses a vectorized version of `outer`:

```
library(qdapTools)
y <- matrix(ncol=no.var,sample(1:5,100*no.var,TRUE))

get.V2<-function(x, y){
    assocstats(table(x, y))$cramer
}
v_outer(y, get.V2)

## > v_outer(y, get.V2)
##       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
## V1 1.000 0.224 0.158 0.195 0.217
## V2 0.224 1.000 0.175 0.163 0.240
## V3 0.158 0.175 1.000 0.208 0.145
## V4 0.195 0.163 0.208 1.000 0.189
## V5 0.217 0.240 0.145 0.189 1.000
```

*Edit*

On 1000 variables these are the system times:

Tyler: Time difference of 38.79437 mins
sgibb: Time difference of 19.54342 mins

Clearly sgibb's approach is superior.

Comment: Thank you. Need to update my R to 3.0.3 for testing with ´qdap` - will take a moment.

Comment: You can cut sgibb's run time in half by using a simpler version of the function to calculation Cramer's V. You should be able to get the runtime down to less than 10 minutes for 1000 variables.